# wp-editor is empty on first submit

Tags: wp-editor

I'm using wp-editor in a simple plugin, but I'm having an issue where the first time I hit the submit button the content from it is blank in the database.

```
<?php 
$editor_id = 'mycontent';       
wp_editor($content, $editor_id );               
?>
```

So I tried alerting the content using this:

```
if (j(".wp-content-wrap").hasClass("tmce-active")){
   alert( tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
}else{
   alert( j('#mycontent').val());
}
```

and the first submit comes up empty. If I switch to the text version before I submit, it works.

What am I doing wrong here that prevents the submit from working?

Edit: Interestingly, if I do this:

```
wp_editor('test', $editor_id );
```

It works.
If I do this:

```
wp_editor('', $editor_id );
```

It doesn't work again.

How do I get it to work if the `$content` is initially blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem.
the submit of content of the wp_editor works not at first-submit, but perfect on second submit.
Another way: Click on the html-button, and then click on the "Vusual"-Button.
I do it with this jquery-statements in my jquery-code to submit the form:

```
$("#post_content-tmce").click();
$("#post_content-html").click();
```

These 2 lines before the $.post-statement makes the content of the editor visible, and submit works.

Answer (score 3):

While debugging same issue in wp_editor, I have found that this issue is related to tinyMCE where its text field does not updated if we try to submit form using ajax call.

A workaround for this is just call `window.tinyMCE.triggerSave()` before doing ajax call something like this:

```
window.tinyMCE.triggerSave();

$.ajax({
    //your ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.
From what I've found, I can't simply pull the data out with javascript, I need to submit it as a form. duh!

I was trying to extract the content from wp-editor via jquery, but simply doing via a form worked better.

```
    function post_product(){
    if(isset($_POST['plug_post_type']) && 'newPost' == $_POST['plug_post_type']){
        $prod_details = array( 

        'title'     => sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_title']),
        'content'   => $_POST['content'],


    );  

    }   
}   
add_action( 'init', 'post_product' );
```